# Use of genesisclient Python library to download data from DEstatis (Official German Statistical Database)

Tags: python, r

I would need to download some national account and household data from [DEstatis](https://www.destatis.de/EN/Service/OpenData/_node.html;jsessionid=1915566DF1A4EFB56BC09E34A10C576D.live742)
Please can you write down some python example of querying a table? the table_id code is 81000-0020
Do I need the account username and password?

P.S. Also solutions in R are appreciated

here the github repository for the python library [genesisclient](https://github.com/marians/genesisclient)

Answer (score 0):

it is literally in the [repo's README...](https://github.com/marians/genesisclient#usage)

So for you: `genesiscl -s DESTATIS -u YOUR_USERNAME -p YOUR_PASSWORD -d 81000-0020`

Yes, you need an account and password.

Comment: thanks, Should I run in the anaconda prompt this line of code right?

Comment: I got an error running `genesiscl -s DESTATIS -u YOUR_USERNAME -p YOUR_PASSWORD -d 81000-0020`

Error:

'Suds module has no attribute Client`


Please do you know how to solve this ``@Damiaan`` ?

Comment: I am afraid not. I do not know this module nor its use cases.